# Using Ubuntu as a router?

Tags: networking, network-manager, routing

I've seen many tools to use Ubuntu as a router in which an internet connection could be shared from Ethernet over Wifi or vice versa. I'm looking to achieve this except with 2 Ethernet connections:

```
Internet --> Computer 1 (with 2 Ethernet cards) --> Computer 2
```

How can I configure Computer 1 to be able to share the connection in the above method. I'm confident in using the terminal or editing config files, but I would much prefer some sort of automated GUI based program such as the settings available in OS X.

I cannot just use a router, I don't have a spare router to use for this temporary set up that I need. I can use any KDE, Gnome or XFCE based tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, if you have KDE I think the easiest applications to use are guarddog and guidedog. Both are in the Ubuntu repositories.

[image]

http://www.simonzone.com/software/guidedog/manual/

http://www.simonzone.com/software/guidedog/

With that said, I would advise you use a firewall / router specific distro, smoothwall is one of several options.

http://www.smoothwall.org/

Smoothwall screenshots (of the web interface)

http://www.smoothwall.org/about/screenshots/

The advantages of smoothwall (or similar) are

1. Pre-configured out of the box / specifically designed for this task.
2. Security. Less packages = more security. A full desktop, such as gnome or kde, let alone X can be a security risk on a router.
3. Web (graphical) interface for easy configuration.
4. Smoothwall web interface has whole sections on traffic monitoring.

So yes, it can be done with Ubuntu, but smoothwall (or similar) is probably easier and in many ways superior.

Comment: Or endian firewall community edition www.endian.com

Comment: Can i have your babies? i'll try it tomorrow but this seems really promising already.